# Scikit-learn Incremental PCA - ValueError: array must not contain infs or NaNs

Tags: scikit-learn, pca, valueerror

I'm trying to use IncrementalPCA from scikit-learn. I really need the incremental version of the algorithm because of the online nature of my application. My code couldn't really be simpler:

```
from sklearn.decomposition import IncrementalPCA
import pandas as pd

with open('C:/My/File/Path/file.csv', 'r') as fp:
    data = pd.read_csv(fp)

ipca = IncrementalPCA(n_components=4)
ipca.fit(data)
```

but this is how it finishes when launched:

```
C:\Users\myuser\PycharmProjects\mushu\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\decomposition\_incremental_pca.py:293: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in long_scalars
  np.sqrt((self.n_samples_seen_ * n_samples) /
C:\Users\myuser\PycharmProjects\mushu\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\decomposition\_incremental_pca.py:293: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sqrt
  np.sqrt((self.n_samples_seen_ * n_samples) /
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/myuser/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2020.1/scratches/scratch_9.py", line 6, in <module>
  ipca.fit(data)
File "C:\Users\myuser\PycharmProjects\mushu\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\decomposition\_incremental_pca.py", line 215, in fit
  self.partial_fit(X_batch, check_input=False)
File "C:\Users\myuser\PycharmProjects\mushu\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\decomposition\_incremental_pca.py", line 298, in partial_fit
  U, S, V = linalg.svd(X, full_matrices=False)
File "C:\Users\myuser\PycharmProjects\mushu\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\decomp_svd.py", line 106, in svd
  a1 = _asarray_validated(a, check_finite=check_finite)
File "C:\Users\myuser\PycharmProjects\mushu\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\_lib\_util.py", line 263, in _asarray_validated
  a = toarray(a)
File "C:\Users\myuser\PycharmProjects\mushu\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 498, in asarray_chkfinite
  raise ValueError(
ValueError: array must not contain infs or NaNs

Process finished with exit code 1
```

My data is 243 columns of only 0s and 1s. I already checked:

- There is no NaN anywhere in my data
- There is no inf anywhere in my data
- I had scikit-learn v0.22.2.post1, I updated to 0.23.1, no difference
- If I use PCA instead of IncrementalPCA leaving everything else the same, everything works fine, no warnings, no errors, all good
- There were similar issues in previous versions, but they refer to versions around 0.16/0.17, most were with more complex code and all were fixed around those versions

If anyone could help me I would be most grateful

**Edit:**
My data, exactly as I feed them to the above code
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JBIliADt9TViTk8qjnmIS3RFEO934dY6/view?usp=sharing

**Edit 2:**
Tried using both

```
data = pd.read_csv(fp, dtype = 'Int64')
```

and

```
data = pd.read_csv(fp, dtype = np.float64)
```

with no difference in results.

**Edit 3:**
Seems like the issue is related with the dataset size. If I try fitting to a smaller portion everything works fine. This is until I get around 1800000 rows. That's where the error starts showing.

Comment: Could you please share your data, so we can try your code? Also what exacty do you want to label if the data contains only 0s and 1s?

Comment: I'm not trying to label anything, I'm using PCA as an anomaly metric. There are only 0s and 1s because each feature indicate the presence or absence of a particular thing, but I think that's beyond the scope of the question. I'm uploading my data file right now.

Comment: I didn't expect that your data was that large :) could you please send a small sample only, with a few rows maybe? You can also try to run your code with that sample just to be sure it works for smaller data.

Comment: @Iammuratc sorry, I'm so accustomed with data if this size that they seem small to me :) I'm doing some test with smaller portions of the dataset, I'll upload a sample as soon as I'm done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I issued this to scikit-learn and they got it fast. This is happening due to numpy array defaulting to int32 on Windows, which causes the RuntimeWarning at the top of the traceback and escalate into having NaNs passed to partial_fit(). I'm temporary moving to Linux waiting for it to be fixed.
[Here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/17693) for anyone having similar problems to track its resolution in future.

**tl;dr:** check above link to see if issue is resolved. If it is not, use a batch_size such as that *batch_size * n_samples < 2^31 - 1*. If that's not possible for you move to Linux.

Comment: I am afraid it might also occur in Linux as I encountered the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong with your data.

Here is an 100% working example using some artificial data (n=2000000 and d=243).
To help more, upload a sample of your data that results in the error.

```
from sklearn.decomposition import IncrementalPCA
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

n=2000000
d=243
data = pd.DataFrame(np.ones((n,d)))

ipca = IncrementalPCA(n_components=4)
ipca.fit(data.values)
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with my data. I issued this to scikit-learn and this is due to numpy array defaulting to int32 on Windows, causing some multiplication to overflow during computation and therefore having NaNs in the array passed to partial_fit() inside fit().